# What are weaknesses of XORing with SecureRandom bytestream

Tags: java, encryption, xor

Quite close to already asked [XOR Encryption in Java: losing data after decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898075/xor-encryption-in-java-losing-data-after-decryption) :

xoring with bytestream produced by seeded SecureRandom looks simple and fast, for example:

```
byte[] data = <data to encrypt>
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
random.setSeed("myPassword".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
byte[] mask = new byte[1];
for(int ii = 0; ii < len; ii++) {
  sr.nextBytes(mask);
  data[ii] = (byte)(0xFF & (data[ii] ^ mask[0]));
}
```

As this approach in not the most used symmetric encrypting, what are it's problems?

Comment: This implements the [one time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) which is aims a way were the cryptanalysis would be impossible. If following constrains are fulfilled. 1) the key has the same length (number of generated random bytes) as the input message 2) you never use the same key again (means the generated random bytes are never in the same order). In your example you never should use the same byte array for `setSeed()`. For an exmplanation for why it's save have a look on the [Attempt at cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad#Attempt_at_cryptanalysis).

Answer (score 1):

Several issues, but the main issue is that if you have only *pseudo*-randomness, then you have *pseudo*-security. True random on the other hand would not give out the same bytes based on a seed, so you'd have to keep the whole keystream handy.

Don't let the `SecureRandom` fool you in that example. Attacking the `SHA1PRNG` algorithm is a lot easier than attacking a real encryption such as `AES`.

Comment: Thank you. 
If I can ask few questions regarding your explanation:
  of course, pseudo-randomness kills the idea of one-time pad. However, the padding stream is still fully based on provided seed and random distributed, so the xor'ed message will be randomly distributed as well, right? The pad could be reproduced just if attacker has original and encrypted messages both - could another, better pseudo-random secureRandom implementation solve it?

Comment: Not really, while a good source of randomness is essential, it's not enough. This is how a stream cipher works, so if you use `AES` in `CTR` mode you'll be xorring the datasream with `AES` being the "securerandom". However issues such as key reuse, and message integrity make a theoretically good idea less useful in practice.

Comment: [Here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10422/why-not-the-one-time-pad-with-pseudo-number-generator), you're not the first one to wonder about that (nor will you be the last).